# Grid Layout CSS is not working as I'd like

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some problems creating this layout:

1: I want to keep the grid layout no matter the size of images that will be dynamicaly generated.

2: Images should keep their aspect ratio (if possible , crop them),

[Demo.](http://jsbin.com/gejus/)

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container"> 

  <div class="row">    

    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/200x250" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/1350x500" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>

  </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
 .thumbnail {  
  overflow: hidden;

}
```

Comment: Your demo looks fine to me. Grid layout and aspect ratio are consistent. What is wrong?

Comment: when images have differents size, the layout is disorgonised...

Answer (score 2):

Your grid lacks the use of multiple rows. Each row needs exactly 12 columns. I added the missing two rows:

**http://jsbin.com/cekojaxu/1/**

Comment: yeah tried this and it worked like I wanted BUT, the problem is, images are dynamicaly loaded... so using different row will mess up the image order...